# How to get value from namspaced XML in PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, curl

I cant seem to access data within xml that is namespaced, it always returns null?

```
<ns1:getMerchByIDResponse xmlns:ns1="URLHERE">
  <ns1:return>
   <ns1:applicationStatus>Approved</ns1:applicationStatus>
  </ns1:return>
</ns1:getMerchByIDResponse>
```

How do i return 'applicationStatus'?

Ive tried decoding to json but returns nothing.